# Service Fabric Single Node SingleNodeClusterUpdateNotAllowed

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've got a single node service fabric instance hosted in Azure, just for testing purposes. When I try and upgrade the service fabric version to 7.0 from 6.5 I get the message:

SingleNodeClusterUpdateNotAllowed

Is there anything I can do to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The reason for this is that in order to upgrade service fabric has to takes down a node, updates and restarts it. This is repeated for all nodes until the update is complete. In a single node cluster this would mean taking the cluster offline completely. This is not allowed by the service fabric rules (at the very least one node must be available). 
A single node 'cluster' therefore cannot update the platform or applications running on it.

The only way you can update a single node cluster is to delete and reinstall it. The same goes for applications (delete the application type before deploying an updated version). Depending on where you have the software deployed (development box, a server, azure) I would recommend scripting as much as possible. This will allow you to easily delete and redeploy. I am using a combination of an Azure template (arm), DevOps pipeline and script to initialise and load some default data into the application.

Comment: The weird thing is, is that I've had this single node test instance for a year and it has happily been updating until version 7 came out.